# TeamCity with showing a modal dialog box

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have ASP.NET MVC application with Azure WebJobs. And I have set to auto publish WebJobs to my Azure Cloud. But when publishing WebJobs via VS there showing modal dialog box. I think that same is in TeamCity but it generating error and publish fails.

How I can disable it and publish WebJobs?

```
        [Step 1/1] 
        [15:19:13][Step 1/1] Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
        [15:19:13][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.RunAsyncTask[T](Task`1 task)
        [15:19:13][Step 1/1]    at Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.Tasks.CreateScheduledWebJob.<>c__DisplayClass1f.<GetAuthorizationHeader>b__1e()
        [15:19:13][Step 1/1]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
        [15:19:13][Step 1/1]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        [15:19:13][Step 1/1]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        [15:19:13][Step 1/1]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        [15:19:13][Step 1/1]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
        [15:19:16][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 255
        [15:19:16][Step 1/1] Step Publish to Azure (with WebJobs) (Command Line) failed
```

Comment: Have you been able to go around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Basically in order to access the azure schedule, authenticated to azure portal is necessary thus the modal to enter credentials.
I manage to go around following this blog:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enabling-command-line-or-continuous-delivery-of-azure-webjobs/

The link to the the azure portal download page is outdated. A newer link can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn414650(v=nav.90).aspx).

Once the publish setting file is downloded, I copied it to our TC server as i didn't want it to be included in the project.

Then I created a webjobs.props file under the Properties folder of the project

[image]

and here is the content:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="AfterSetScheduleProperties" AfterTargets="SetScheduleProperties">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishSettingsPath>C:\Local_Properties\Azure\FileName.publishsettings</PublishSettingsPath>
        <SubscriptionId>XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXX</SubscriptionId>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

I found the subscription id in the publish setting file I downloaded.
The publish setting file path is the path on the TC server.

Now the schedule is correctly created/updated on azure when publishing the webjob.

Hope this help